# Unable to get the dropdown to close using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

Here is the fiddle containing all the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rajat_bansal/rtapaew5/1/

Here is my jquery part which is causing problems:-

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

        $(".sub-handle").click(function() {
           if(!$(this).hasClass('showing-sub')){ //class doesnt exists so add     it and open dropdowns giving specific backgrounds
            $(this).find(".submenu").addClass('showing-sub');
            $(this).addClass("sidebarElementDivOnClick");
            $(this).find("a").addClass("outerMenuItem");
          }
          else{ 
              $(this).find(".submenu").removeClass("showing-sub");
         }
      });

      $(".innerMenuItem").click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("innerMenuItemOnClick");
      });
    });
```

From what I see, its not letting me remove the class. I guess its something minor. Im very new to jquery. Any help with explanation would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were simply checking the wrong element for the class. I also added necessary code to remove the classes when the menu closes.

```
$(".sub-link").click(function() {
    if(!$('.submenu').hasClass('showing-sub')){ //class doesnt exists so add it and open dropdowns giving specific backgrounds
        $(".sub-handle").find(".submenu").addClass('showing-sub');
        $(".sub-handle").addClass("sidebarElementDivOnClick");
        $(".sub-handle").find("a").addClass("outerMenuItem");
    } else { //if class exists..that means it was clicked again
        $(".sub-handle").find(".submenu").removeClass("showing-sub");
        $(".sub-handle").removeClass("sidebarElementDivOnClick");
        $(".sub-handle").find("a").removeClass("outerMenuItem");
    }
});
```

I've updated your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rtapaew5/6/).

Comment: But here is the thing..the dropdown should close only if I click on the main menu item and not the dropdown item. For example, when i click on sub menu item it should turn white and if i click on it again it should come back to original color. Check my fiddle to see what I mean. Dropdown should close only when I click on Main menu item.

Comment: @RajatBansal I've updated the fiddle in my answer. You have to use the link for the event and not the `<li>`, since the list item expands to the size of the whole dropdown thus gets a click event invoked whenever you click on a dropdown link.

Comment: thx a lot daniel..i need to work on the way i visualize things..thx again!

Answer (score -1):

YOu have wrong condition in jquery :

Your condition should be

```
if(! $(this).find(".submenu").hasClass('showing-sub')){
```

OR

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('sidebarElementDivOnClick')){
```

Check [**https://jsfiddle.net/rtapaew5/4/**](https://jsfiddle.net/rtapaew5/4/)

For Status anchor tag click event : [**https://jsfiddle.net/rtapaew5/7/**](https://jsfiddle.net/rtapaew5/7/)

Comment: But here is the thing..the dropdown should close only if I click on the main menu item and not the dropdown item. For example, when i click on sub menu item it should turn white and if i click on it again it should come back to original color. Check my fiddle to see what I mean. Dropdown should close only when I click on Main menu item.

Comment: @RajatBansal then you need to fire click event on **status** anchor tag : Please check https://jsfiddle.net/rtapaew5/7/

Comment: @RajatBansal You welcome, you can up vote and accept answer

Comment: Nice to see the appreciate